# Finding first occurrence of each digit in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Taking each four digit number of an array in turn, return the number that you are on when all of the digits 0-9 have been discovered. If not all of the digits can be found, return "Missing digits!"

I've tried to loop through then set a conditional if (i != i+1) push into new array this just gave me the array, it's apparent my logic is wrong. could anyone help me out

For example calling this function with

```
arr = findAllDigits([5175, 4538, 2926, 5057, 6401, 4376, 2280, 6137, 8798, 9083])
```

the code should return 5057.

While calling

```
arr = findAllDigits([4883, 3876, 7769, 9846, 9546, 9634, 9696, 2832, 6822, 6868])
```

should return "missing numbers"

```
function findAllDigits(arr) {
  newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) newArr.push(arr[i]);
    console.log(newArr);
  }
}
```

Do I need to split because it is taking everything before the comma as
one number, then iterate over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more solution:

```
const arr1 = [5175, 4538, 2926, 5057, 6401, 4376, 2280, 6137, 8798, 9083];
const arr2 = [4883, 3876, 7769, 9846, 9546, 9634, 9696, 2832, 6822, 6868];
            
const findAllDigits = (arr) => {

    // Declare new Set: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set
  const digits = new Set();

    // return the first item from array that fits the condition, 
    // find() method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
  return arr.find((curr) => (

      // String(5175) -> '5175' : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String
      // [...'5175'] ->  ['5','1','7','5'] : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
      // .forEach(digits.add, digits) - forEach with callback function and context : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
      // comma operator lets get rid of return : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator
    [...String(curr)].forEach(digits.add, digits),

      // condition - is find() method need to return an item  
    (digits.size === 10)
     
    // if returned value is not undefined or null return finded number oterwise error string
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator
  )) ?? "Missing digits!";
};
                
console.log(findAllDigits(arr1)); //5057
console.log(findAllDigits(arr2)); //Missing digits!
```

Comment: would you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: @che2programmer I added comments describing how each line works, with links to documentation

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) here

Loop over the `array` and then create a `set`, You have to return the current number if `set` size becomes `10` because you need to check `0-9`

```js
function findAllDigits(arr) {
  const set = new Set();
  for (let n of arr) {
    String(n)
      .split("")
      .forEach((c) => set.add(c));
    if (set.size === 10) return n;
  }
  return "Missing digits!";
}

const arr1 = [5175, 4538, 2926, 5057, 6401, 4376, 2280, 6137, 8798, 9083];
const arr2 = [4883, 3876, 7769, 9846, 9546, 9634, 9696, 2832, 6822, 6868];
console.log(findAllDigits(arr1));
console.log(findAllDigits(arr2));
```

Comment: Simple and beauty

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop is only checking to see if the array entry is equal to the next one. You need to split up the digits inside each entry and store them individually:

```
function findAllDigits(arr) {
  newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // now iterate the individual digits
    const entryAsString = arr[i].toString();
    for (let j = 0; j < entryAsString.length; j++) {
      // if we haven't seen the digit before, add it to the array
      if(!newArr.includes(j) {
        newArr.push(j);
      }
    }
    // we know we have all digits when newArr is 10 entries long
    if (newArr.length) {
      console.log(arr[i]);
      // you can also return this value here
    }
  }
}
```